# "Bedeutung geben an" geht nicht auf Deutsch, aber wie kann ich das beschreiben/nennen?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, usage, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

Ich bin gerade an einer Studie und muss sie auf Deutsch schreiben. Ich habe da folgendes Problem:

Die Schüler nennen am Ende einer Unterrichtsstunde Sätze (die sie selber bilden) zu einer bestimmten Vokabel. Mit welchem Begriff kann man diesen Prozess am besten beschreiben? Auf Niederländisch würde man „Bedeutung geben an“ sagen, auf Deutsch geht das aber leider nicht.

Comment: Ich rate mal was gemeint ist: Die Kinder sollen den Sinn eines Wortes verstanden haben und das mit einem Satz zeigen. Dafür könnte man auf deutsch z. B. sagen: Verständnistest

Comment: ***Produktive** Verwendung der erlernten Vokabeln.* Im Gegensatz zum reinen Sprachverständnis.

Comment: Sollen die Kinder Beispiele nennen? Kannst Du die Phrase auf Niederländisch in einem ganzen Satz zeigen? "Die Bedeutung angeben" kennen wir, aber das wäre etwas anderes als Beispiele bilden. Ich verstehe nicht, was gemeint ist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *Vokabeln im Kontext verwenden*
- *Sätze mit Vokabeln bilden*

  oder nur
- *Sätze bilden*

Comment: Diese Antwort kann ich am Besten in den Text einbauen. Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 3):

> Vokabeln in Sätze einbinden / integrieren / einfügen

wären auch noch Möglichkeiten. Ich würde wohl »einbinden« wählen.

Answer (score 2):

Unter der Voraussetzung, dass der niederländische Begriff

> betekenis geven

ist, dann wäre eine wörtliche Übersetzung dieses Begriff beispielsweise

> Bedeutung verleihen.

Mit dem Kontext aus der Frage sind aber tofros Vorschläge besser geeignet als die wörtliche Übersetzung.

Comment: Der Ausdruck in der Herkunftssprache war hier wichtig!  - Auf Deutsch würde ich sagen: "Einen Satz bilden", oder ganz simpel: "das Wort anwenden".